# ASP.NET MVC Post Collection CamelCase Serialization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, controller, deserialization

XOn an ASP.NET MVC Website I´m posting a List of models, wrapped in a classe's property, by submitting a form. 
When the "List propertys" name contains a 
capital letter beside the first one, deserialization seems to fail when posting back, hence the List property of the wrapping class received as parameter in the controller method is null. If the propertie`s name doesn't contain any further capital letters all going fine.

For better comprehension I created an example with two wrapping classes Department & DepartmentX:

```
namespace CollectionPropertyCamelCase.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Department
    {
        public IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }

    public class DepartmentX
    {
        public IList<Employee> EmployeesX { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace CollectionPropertyCamelCase.Controllers
{
    public class DepartmentController : Controller
    {
        // ---> Works fine
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var d = new Department()
            {
                Employees = new List<Employee>()
                {
                    new Employee(){ Name = "Paul", Age = 35},
                    new Employee(){ Name = "Laura", Age = 27},
                    new Employee(){ Name = "John", Age = 99}
                }
            };
            return View(d);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Department d)
        {
            // All fine: Parameter d`s poperty Employees is an instance of 
            // List<Employee> conatining three instances of Employee
            // providing the values as defined in Index(). 
            return View(d);
        }
        // <--- Works fine

        // ---> Doesn't work 
        public ActionResult IndexX()
        {
            var d = new DepartmentX()
            {
                // this is the troublemaker: Usage of 'X' in the propertyname
                EmployeesX = new List<Employee>()
                {
                    new Employee(){ Name = "Paul", Age = 35},
                    new Employee(){ Name = "Laura", Age = 27},
                    new Employee(){ Name = "John", Age = 99}
                }
            };
            return View(d);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult IndexX(DepartmentX d)
        {
            // Not so fine: Parameter d`s poperty EmployeesX is null
            return View(d);
        }
        // <--- Doesn't work
    }
}

@* Index.cshtml *@
@model CollectionPropertyCamelCase.Models.Department
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Employees.Count; i ++)
    { 
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Employees[i].Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.Employees[i].Age)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }   
    </table>
    <input type="submit" />
}

@* IndexX.cshtml *@
@model CollectionPropertyCamelCase.Models.DepartmentX
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "IndexX";
}
<h2>IndexX</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.EmployeesX.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.EmployeesX[i].Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.EmployeesX[i].Age)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }     
    </table>
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Does anyone have a clue how to influence deserialization, so camelcased propery names can be used at that place? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It has nothing to do with CamelCase (or any casing). The `DefaultModelBinder` is not case sensitive. If your collection is not binding, its because you have not generated the controls with the correct name attributes. I have tested your code and it works fine - the model in both post methods are correctly bound so you have not included the correct code

Comment: The binding/rendering works fine, trouble starts when submitting the form to controllermethod 'IndexX': The received parameter of type 'DepartmentX's property 'EmployeesX' is null. But, when I submit the form to controllermethod 'Index' the instance of parameter 'Department'  all is fine i.e. it`s property Employees is an instance of List<Employee> containing the three instances of type Employee. The only difference between class DepartmentX & Department is the naming of it`s property which contains the 'Employee' instances (EmployeesX vs. Employees).

Comment: I have already copied the code in your question to a new project and it works - it binds correctly in both cases, so the code you have posted is not the real code.

Comment: Hence I thought trouble occured while deserialization...

Comment: **It works** There is no problem with the code you have posted.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Stephen, I guess you got me wrong, the problem is not about binding/displaying the values on the website, but when posting back the form.

Comment: I repeat, I have cut and pasted the code you have posted in your question into a new project and it works. It binds to the models when you post back in both methods. `Employees` and `EmployeesX` both contain the 3 items. There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code you have posted.

Comment: I can't believe it but  you are right, since i restarted iis, it`s working now. Thanks a lot for your effort again, next time i`ll capture a video ...